# Class initialised inside another class, how does it survive?

Tags: c++, class

So I have a class called List which stores a vector of pointers to classes of type Object. List has a function called add which initialises an Object class and adds it's pointer to the vector. I thought that once the add function ended that the Object class would be destroyed and accessing the pointer would cause an exception. When I wrote a test program to test this it turned out that the Object class was never destroyed.

Are classes initialised inside a function ever destroyed once the function ends?

When are classes automatically destroyed?

Comment: Classes are never destroyed; objects are. When/how objects are destroyed depends on how they are created. How are you creating your objects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends how you're creating the object. If you are doing it like this:

```
void add() {
  Object obj;
  vec.push_back(&obj);
}
```

Then you are creating `obj` with *automatic storage duration*. That means it will be destroyed when the `add` function ends. The pointer you have pushed into the vector will no longer point to a valid `Object`, so definitely don't do this.

You may, however, be doing this:

```
void add() {
  Object* obj = new Object();
  vec.push_back(obj);
}
```

If you are, you are creating the `Object` with *dynamic storage duration* and it will not be destroyed at the end of the function. The pointer you push into the vector will remain valid. However, if you do this, you need to remember to `delete` the object at a later time. If you don't, you'll have a leak.

The best option is to avoid using pointers at all, if you can. Just make the vector a `std::vector<Object>` and copy objects into it:

```
void add() {
  vec.push_back(Object());
}
```

Or in C++11:

```
void add() {
  vec.emplace_back();
}
```

If you really need pointers, prefer smart pointers.

Comment: Vector of objects, not pointers? Not a good idea, event for simple cases. Object may contains pointers which may be lost on sorting. moving, etc.

Comment: Your "best option" relies on proper implementation of copy constructors.  Noting the extra copy is very important here.

Comment: @AlexG.P. Not if the copy constructor is written correctly. Avoiding raw pointers is a great way to write safer code.

Answer (score -1):

In C++, if you don't use any memory manager, smart pointers or some kind of "managed" environment, classes created using keyword *new*. To avoid misunderstanding could you please post constructor of Object and method List.Add?

So, when you are creating new object like:

```
Object* o = new Object();
```

you reserving space in the heap and store pointer to that space in pointer 'o'. If you never calling

```
delete o;
```

explicitly your object will never deleted.